# How to duplicate a database without adding extra data via cPanel or PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to duplicate database using PHPAdmin, but everytime I duplicate the database it adds about **9-15MB** of data to it.

MySQL database original size. **15.2 MB**

I've tried all these options below...

[image]

...doubles in size **30 MB**

[image]

...doubles in size **30 MB**

[image]

...adds about **9 MB**

I don't understand why a direct copy using the operations tab in PHPMyAdmin adds extra data everytime.

[image]

How do I duplicate the database like for like. An exact copy with no extra data?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You use `structure only`. The option you didn't screenshot so it appears as if you didn't try it. Even when you create an empty database, some space will be allocated to it.

Comment: @Mjh Ah I thought `structure` was the tables, so it was necessary for the data. If I do just `structure only` then my copied database size is `1.23 MB` which cant be right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do.. when you duplicate the database, it copies the data. Space on the disk expands and the amount of space allocated **doesn't correspond** to the database dump. I thought you wanted to duplicate the structure without data. Whatever you do with data and database duplication won't be intuitive. MySQL storage engines choose how to use the space, so what PHPMyAdmin or any other script reports is probably entirely false and shouldn't be relied upon.

Comment: This is basically an EXPORT you are talking about right. So this new size you are looking at, is that the RESTORED database or the `.sql` file that the export creates

Comment: @Mjh so your saying the size data that is shown in cPanel is not actually the size of the database?

Comment: @RiggsFolly i'm using the `Copy database to` in the `Operations` tab in PhpMyAdmin. Is this the same as and export? I thought it would be just a straight copy.

Comment: I really think that the main focus of your attention should be that the data is all there. For example row counts. MySQL will resize the files that contain the data to suit itself.

Comment: @RiggsFolly ok cool, I just wasn't sure if I was doing something wrong.

Comment: I haven't used cPanel in decades, but I wouldn't trust it to be 100% correct. The only way to know how much space MySQL uses is to check its data file size before and after duplicating the database. However, what RiggsFolly wrote - just make sure the data is there, not that megabytes match. MySQL will take care of its needs, all that's important is that data is there.